# Finding effect of a variable on NPS of a survey responses

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, data-visualization

I have a survey responses data. It has various columns, but one of the column is the age of the product usage by the user. The other column is the response given by the user on a 0-10 point scale as used to calculate NPS.

Now I have calculated NPS using this response variable but what I also want is how does Age variable impact NPS score. Any visualization or model which can help explain that.

NPS is calculated based on the below function I wrote which takes in responses of all users and finds Promoters_Proportion(9 &10) and Detractors_proportion (0-6)

```
def nps_score(responses): 
    """Function to get the NPS score from the 
     Survey responses 

    """
    global sample_size,promoters_proportion,detractors_proportion,sample_NPS

    sample_size = len(responses)
    promoters_proportion = sum([1 for x in responses if x >=9])/sample_size
    detractors_proportion= sum([1 for x in responses if x<=6])/sample_size

    sample_NPS= promoters_proportion - detractors_proportion

    print("Sample Net Promoter Score(NPS) is {} or {}%".
          format(round(sample_NPS,2),round(sample_NPS*100,2)))
```

I can plot correlation or a regression model between age and responses, but NPS is calculated from all the responses (%promoters- %detractors). So not sure how to do this.

Any ideas/help wud be appreciated.

Sample Data below is Age (in days), Response of a user

```
array([['161.791365740741', 8.0],
       ['40.7387384259259', 7.0],
       ['1,289.49306712963', 8.0],
       ['32.3515277777778', 5.0],
       ['1,082.74270833333', 8.0],
       ['538.689490740741', 7.0],
       ['276.823541666667', 10.0],
       ['1,249.75631944444', 10.0],
       ['75.5923611111111', 10.0],
       ['248.181539351852', 6.0],
       ['2,427.55869212963', 8.0],
       ['772.878356481481', 10.0],
       ['1,475.76710648148', 10.0],
       ['1,560.73618055556', 10.0],
       ['211.118738425926', 10.0],
       ['686.884409722222', 10.0],
       ['1,377.74114583333', 9.0],
       ['1,548.9194212963', 10.0],
       ['20.0154166666667', 5.0],
       ['1,039.62513888889', 3.0],
       ['84.2223032407407', 4.0],
       ['182.914525462963', 10.0],
       ['34.0710648148148', 3.0],
       ['771.650115740741', 10.0],
       ['1,107.72900462963', 8.0],
       ['900.200601851852', 10.0],
       ['1,402.0755787037', 9.0],
       ['1,051.76541666667', 7.0],
       ['1,170.68356481481', 10.0],
       ['823.899490740741', 10.0],
       ['585.916840277778', nan],
       ['1,292.40875', 7.0],
       ['187.735451388889', 7.0],
       ['640.244479166667', 10.0],
       ['616.626041666667', 8.0],
       ['567.984282407407', 7.0],
       ['179.260972222222', 9.0],
       ['1,183.66049768519', 9.0],
       ['726.202060185185', 10.0],
       ['1,468.16413194444', 10.0],
       ['1,405.9825462963', 10.0],
       ['552.079872685185', 7.0],
       ['936.559409722222', 7.0],
       ['5.74927083333333', 9.0],
       ['1,093.39606481481', 10.0],
       ['123.436365740741', 10.0],
       ['822.616539351852', 7.0],
       ['900.386782407407', 9.0],
       ['2,292.46261574074', 10.0],
       ['50.3718055555556', 7.0],
       ['2,063.72606481481', 10.0],
       ['594.851030092593', 8.0],
       ['254.721631944444', 10.0],
       ['1,369.10880787037', 10.0],
       ['898.011886574074', 8.0],
       ['1,478.0727662037', 10.0],
       ['2,089.75056712963', 10.0],
       ['7.1574537037037', 8.0],
       ['1,513.59943287037', 8.0],
       ['1,901.51211805556', 8.0],
       ['234.168159722222', 8.0],
       ['1,182.57590277778', 10.0],
       ['246.701319444444', 7.0],
       ['575.854097222222', 8.0],
       ['295.627685185185', 8.0],
       ['1,340.86450231481', 10.0],
       ['1,268.80829861111', 9.0],
       ['841.929421296296', 7.0],
       ['368.967303240741', 7.0],
       ['80.8581018518519', 9.0],
       ['263.413402777778', 9.0],
       ['131.503541666667', 7.0],
       ['1,120.79670138889', 8.0],
       ['1,483.36947916667', 10.0],
       ['137.255740740741', 9.0],
       ['1,292.38701388889', 8.0],
       ['107.443009259259', 7.0],
       ['856.452731481481', 10.0],
       ['61.2199652777778', 8.0],
       ['1,107.00429398148', 10.0],
       ['478.670486111111', 10.0],
       ['984.223726851852', 9.0],
       ['1,005.49194444444', 10.0],
       ['581.8559375', 10.0],
       ['258.861053240741', 8.0],
       ['17.0186805555556', 7.0],
       ['232.950775462963', 10.0],
       ['462.759664351852', 8.0],
       ['1,823.63902777778', 8.0],
       ['874.004710648148', 8.0],
       ['34.6446643518519', 8.0],
       ['877.664537037037', 8.0],
       ['290.054953703704', 10.0],
       ['1,115.28671296296', 10.0],
       ['826.945069444444', 7.0],
       ['1,463.68288194444', 10.0],
       ['483.195798611111', 7.0],
       ['1,979.52415509259', 10.0],
       ['258.273900462963', 8.0],
       ['398.91869212963', 10.0],
       ['1,486.39513888889', 10.0],
       ['55.128125', 9.0],
       ['2,270.38100694444', 9.0],
       ['687.942974537037', 9.0],
       ['1,204.79081018519', 10.0],
       ['1,442.01534722222', 8.0],
       ['292.533993055556', 10.0],
       ['834.622488425926', 10.0],
       ['162.647974537037', 10.0],
       ['1,399.181875', 9.0],
       ['58.9229282407407', 10.0],
       ['35.6341666666667', 7.0],
       ['1,933.00869212963', 10.0],
       ['771.54931712963', 10.0],
       ['23.4971759259259', 5.0],
       ['578.16025462963', 10.0],
       ['672.142002314815', 10.0],
       ['300.687222222222', 9.0],
       ['1,617.52157407407', 10.0],
       ['1,832.98153935185', 10.0],
       ['629.690231481482', 10.0],
       ['999.701736111111', 10.0],
       ['241.726689814815', 7.0],
       ['435.485983796296', 7.0],
       ['1,533.47179398148', 10.0],
       ['613.732743055556', 10.0],
       ['974.660601851852', 2.0],
       ['42.2435648148148', 10.0],
       ['1,360.26850694444', 10.0],
       ['325.723275462963', 10.0],
       ['1,373.64803240741', 8.0],
       ['1,258.60865740741', 7.0],
       ['19.9585300925926', 10.0],
       ['203.8459375', 10.0],
       ['1,278.40819444444', 10.0],
       ['259.408217592593', 10.0],
       ['1,576.99164351852', 7.0],
       ['246.7684375', 10.0],
       ['184.427824074074', 10.0],
       ['992.558981481482', 10.0],
       ['838.921423611111', 10.0],
       ['479.6646875', 8.0],
       ['738.583310185185', 10.0],
       ['280.303530092593', 0.0],
       ['345.668020833333', 9.0],
       ['875.26755787037', 8.0],
       ['618.205381944444', 10.0],
       ['1,103.3741087963', 8.0],
       ['1,766.14503472222', 8.0],
       ['174.334108796296', 10.0],
       ['1,310.74164351852', 9.0],
       ['432.800069444444', 5.0],
       ['100.604803240741', 10.0],
       ['35.9965277777778', 5.0],
       ['720.647280092593', 10.0],
       ['981.174259259259', 7.0],
       ['576.641527777778', 10.0],
       ['586.719861111111', 10.0],
       ['252.410231481481', 8.0],
       ['1,363.01680555556', 8.0],
       ['1,557.67414351852', 8.0],
       ['635.06099537037', 10.0],
       ['163.226770833333', 8.0],
       ['583.811863425926', 8.0],
       ['1,339.17377314815', 10.0],
       ['556.255636574074', 9.0],
       ['938.865509259259', 7.0],
       ['395.304027777778', 10.0],
       ['193.883275462963', 10.0],
       ['1,807.12388888889', 9.0],
       ['779.201921296296', 9.0],
       ['1,027.48635416667', 10.0],
       ['329.159305555556', 10.0],
       ['904.388460648148', 10.0],
       ['1,287.7896412037', 5.0],
       ['7.57591435185185', 5.0],
       ['378.9171875', 8.0],
       ['57.8599421296296', 5.0],
       ['235.897395833333', 7.0],
       ['1.7856712962963', 1.0],
       ['676.808888888889', 7.0],
       ['582.710104166667', 10.0],
       ['193.595115740741', 10.0],
       ['609.192581018518', 10.0],
       ['1,224.40655092593', 9.0],
       ['805.788460648148', 9.0],
       ['639.303923611111', 10.0],
       ['324.306168981482', 8.0],
       ['606.191296296296', 10.0],
       ['517.245578703704', 10.0],
       ['161.009340277778', 10.0],
       ['1,104.19155092593', 10.0],
       ['827.621828703704', 8.0],
       ['575.602037037037', 10.0],
       ['14.9346527777778', 10.0],
       ['700.285902777778', 8.0],
       ['1,058.22909722222', 8.0],
       ['77.4969097222222', 10.0],
       ['50.9143634259259', 7.0],
       ['698.884143518518', 8.0],
       ['248.050127314815', 7.0],
       ['191.0190625', 8.0],
       ['692.792951388889', 10.0],
       ['253.955115740741', 8.0],
       ['836.749027777778', 10.0],
       ['926.109872685185', 10.0],
       ['1,379.29163194444', 9.0],
       ['320.706041666667', 8.0],
       ['19.7178240740741', 10.0],
       ['3.72481481481482', 0.0],
       ['343.840810185185', 7.0],
       ['1,668.57377314815', 8.0],
       ['622.477696759259', 10.0],
       ['42.4566898148148', 6.0],
       ['1,726.68545138889', 10.0],
       ['117.791875', 3.0],
       ['235.919108796296', 8.0],
       ['797.249085648148', 10.0],
       ['1,373.27986111111', 10.0],
       ['1,478.20516203704', 8.0],
       ['593.970636574074', 8.0],
       ['722.501076388889', 10.0],
       ['58.1993981481481', 10.0],
       ['1,076.18219907407', 10.0],
       ['725.910439814815', 10.0],
       ['35.1732407407407', 7.0],
       ['90.7518518518519', 6.0],
       ['968.129814814815', 10.0],
       ['842.622592592593', 8.0],
       ['601.600983796296', 5.0],
       ['657.604953703704', 10.0],
       ['365.144675925926', 5.0],
       ['43.2231481481481', 8.0],
       ['501.675393518519', 8.0],
       ['244.55087962963', 10.0],
       ['1,331.15416666667', 10.0],
       ['964.019363425926', 10.0],
       ['1,212.17709490741', 8.0],
       ['50.2955092592593', 3.0],
       ['489.15130787037', 3.0],
       ['700.209189814815', 10.0],
       ['369.843842592593', nan],
       ['238.922106481481', 10.0],
       ['489.465601851852', 10.0],
       ['776.302326388889', 10.0],
       ['427.892824074074', 10.0],
       ['396.172731481481', 4.0],
       ['32.0659490740741', 10.0],
       ['1,574.27050925926', 10.0],
       ['749.799467592593', 10.0],
       ['155.807858796296', 10.0],
       ['501.195451388889', 9.0],
       ['122.124247685185', 10.0],
       ['1,529.4178125', 7.0],
       ['65.5540625', 10.0],
       ['789.075798611111', 10.0],
       ['1,139.14309027778', 6.0],
       ['1,600.21114583333', 10.0],
       ['800.587141203704', 10.0],
       ['623.265659722222', 7.0],
       ['546.029016203704', 10.0],
       ['260.17931712963', 10.0],
       ['677.042233796296', 7.0],
       ['793.68787037037', 7.0],
       ['539.007789351852', 10.0],
       ['1,121.26221064815', 10.0],
       ['948.034143518518', 8.0],
       ['918.66369212963', 10.0],
       ['797.644363425926', 10.0],
       ['26.9296643518519', 10.0],
       ['438.359733796296', 7.0],
       ['165.38181712963', 10.0],
       ['1,259.17831018519', 10.0],
       ['371.515393518519', 10.0],
       ['96.2371296296296', 10.0],
       ['1,419.80189814815', 8.0],
       ['750.4528125', 9.0],
       ['580.449282407407', 10.0],
       ['2,226.85815972222', 10.0],
       ['843.764201388889', 10.0],
       ['1,901.42866898148', 9.0],
       ['1,100.31225694444', 8.0],
       ['449.41900462963', 9.0],
       ['976.930324074074', 10.0],
       ['637.029340277778', 8.0],
       ['1,012.00993055556', 10.0],
       ['69.8599652777778', 10.0],
       ['1,694.03460648148', 8.0],
       ['848.519664351852', 8.0],
       ['750.646342592593', 10.0],
       ['1,364.12494212963', 10.0],
       ['293.890034722222', 10.0],
       ['121.680844907407', 9.0],
       ['822.869918981482', 8.0],
       ['2,383.79436342593', 10.0],
       ['650.345648148148', 10.0],
       ['957.8828125', 10.0],
       ['614.039224537037', 9.0],
       ['2,141.35708333333', 8.0],
       ['1,278.49892361111', 10.0],
       ['673.761527777778', 10.0],
       ['652.164583333333', 8.0],
       ['903.277951388889', 10.0],
       ['479.709791666667', 10.0],
       ['1,531.29196759259', 10.0],
       ['69.0719212962963', 8.0],
       ['252.788668981481', 10.0],
       ['1,093.02025462963', 10.0],
       ['1,500.07123842593', 10.0],
       ['133.04880787037', 9.0],
       ['235.226689814815', 10.0],
       ['323.965659722222', 10.0],
       ['765.521319444444', 8.0],
       ['947.920219907407', 10.0],
       ['628.946516203704', 10.0],
       ['1,421.54715277778', 10.0],
       ['1,754.78592592593', 5.0],
       ['1,047.92363425926', 10.0],
       ['296.814965277778', 9.0],
       ['818.082048611111', 10.0],
       ['1,779.72524305556', 9.0],
       ['173.928449074074', 5.0],
       ['1,304.54969907407', 10.0],
       ['187.880266203704', 10.0],
       ['1,099.78331018519', 8.0],
       ['563.43724537037', 9.0],
       ['104.696863425926', 8.0],
       ['624.34787037037', 9.0],
       ['808.919155092593', 10.0],
       ['366.30244212963', 5.0],
       ['1,083.95248842593', 10.0],
       ['718.412881944444', 10.0],
       ['1,260.78216435185', 10.0],
       ['212.923402777778', 8.0],
       ['215.357974537037', 10.0],
       ['859.924224537037', 10.0],
       ['1,309.41909722222', 10.0],
       ['698.573935185185', 10.0],
       ['661.043842592593', 10.0],
       ['1,423.65903935185', 10.0],
       ['1,384.5830787037', 8.0],
       ['1,191.38708333333', 9.0],
       ['1,216.99390046296', 10.0],
       ['893.468668981482', 9.0],
       ['249.591759259259', 10.0],
       ['575.977743055556', 10.0],
       ['514.922118055556', 9.0],
       ['1,149.72403935185', 9.0],
       ['5.79609953703704', 7.0],
       ['233.431770833333', 9.0],
       ['175.655555555556', 10.0],
       ['583.647222222222', 10.0],
       ['42.2107060185185', 7.0],
       ['1,407.40928240741', 9.0],
       ['622.65255787037', 6.0],
       ['784.093090277778', 9.0],
       ['928.909583333333', 9.0],
       ['693.729988425926', 10.0],
       ['724.917800925926', 7.0],
       ['978.842534722222', 10.0],
       ['211.954236111111', 8.0],
       ['498.819340277778', 9.0],
       ['1,846.73799768519', 7.0],
       ['681.182777777778', 10.0],
       ['697.477997685185', 10.0],
       ['977.904212962963', 10.0],
       ['1,452.90467592593', 10.0],
       ['1,168.50965277778', 7.0],
       ['1,399.97071759259', 10.0],
       ['99.9097453703704', 10.0],
       ['1,231.94563657407', 10.0],
       ['622.668587962963', 10.0],
       ['637.831747685185', 6.0],
       ['999.448275462963', 10.0],
       ['382.870185185185', 5.0],
       ['8.77283564814815', 8.0],
       ['58.0656134259259', 10.0],
       ['1,611.46561342593', 7.0],
       ['64.7844212962963', 8.0],
       ['885.418888888889', 10.0],
       ['1,840.45140046296', 10.0],
       ['859.835462962963', 9.0],
       ['508.983703703704', 7.0],
       ['792.851412037037', 10.0],
       ['400.945497685185', 6.0],
       ['890.991064814815', 10.0],
       ['281.839398148148', 8.0],
       ['1,127.90708333333', 9.0],
       ['335.00931712963', 8.0],
       ['1,176.8309837963', 8.0],
       ['643.735740740741', 8.0],
       ['2,257.76168981481', 10.0],
       ['630.984675925926', 10.0],
       ['759.872847222222', 9.0],
       ['1,136.96646990741', 8.0],
       ['550.404571759259', 10.0],
       ['594.812083333333', 10.0],
       ['481.040509259259', 9.0],
       ['204.389490740741', 7.0],
       ['347.707175925926', 10.0],
       ['1,017.4821412037', 10.0],
       ['1,792.4609837963', 8.0],
       ['99.9463310185185', 10.0],
       ['891.628136574074', 9.0],
       ['679.612326388889', 10.0],
       ['1,155.52712962963', 8.0],
       ['680.894270833333', 9.0],
       ['1,231.65739583333', 7.0],
       ['692.122222222222', 9.0],
       ['2,182.7012037037', 10.0],
       ['501.544074074074', 10.0],
       ['1,112.83163194444', 8.0],
       ['951.765520833333', 10.0],
       ['1,453.7821412037', 8.0],
       ['146.781666666667', 10.0],
       ['2,087.64082175926', 9.0],
       ['733.755613425926', 10.0],
       ['1,091.5716087963', 10.0],
       ['1,053.91412037037', 6.0],
       ['1,080.61337962963', 10.0],
       ['144.56744212963', 8.0],
       ['477.645902777778', 9.0],
       ['276.823541666667', 10.0],
       ['554.686053240741', 8.0],
       ['348.631828703704', 10.0],
       ['562.756527777778', 10.0],
       ['407.743900462963', 9.0],
       ['539.41599537037', 8.0],
       ['472.732210648148', 8.0],
       ['1,696.5834837963', 10.0],
       ['1,025.16728009259', 10.0],
       ['460.872037037037', 6.0],
       ['1,152.67767361111', 10.0],
       ['12.8458796296296', 9.0],
       ['706.971273148148', 9.0],
       ['29.9339699074074', 10.0],
       ['36.0250925925926', 10.0],
       ['1,141.16350694444', 7.0],
       ['597.963159722222', 8.0],
       ['1,391.60329861111', 10.0],
       ['744.577638888889', 8.0],
       ['200.641412037037', 7.0],
       ['47.048587962963', 8.0],
       ['837.549351851852', 7.0],
       ['1,529.75857638889', 9.0],
       ['1,305.55780092593', 9.0],
       ['1,904.63177083333', 10.0],
       ['736.049525462963', 10.0],
       ['209.619212962963', 8.0],
       ['1,527.69133101852', 10.0],
       ['614.440960648148', 10.0],
       ['2,407.51556712963', 9.0],
       ['457.06431712963', 10.0],
       ['259.812673611111', 10.0],
       ['1,314.01947916667', 10.0],
       ['174.932685185185', 6.0],
       ['1,471.93626157407', 10.0],
       ['474.935972222222', 10.0],
       ['1,254.47523148148', 10.0],
       ['404.774178240741', 8.0],
       ['1,055.49863425926', 10.0],
       ['921.656597222222', 9.0],
       ['65.8047916666667', 8.0],
       ['21.813900462963', 9.0],
       ['1,187.67599537037', 10.0],
       ['825.708240740741', 8.0],
       ['40.7039467592593', 10.0],
       ['321.741145833333', 8.0],
       ['723.28443287037', 10.0],
       ['1,755.83092592593', 8.0],
       ['1,820.59570601852', 10.0],
       ['6.41877314814815', 10.0],
       ['990.461145833333', 10.0],
       ['1,248.19627314815', 10.0],
       ['588.854282407407', 10.0],
       ['2,381.26219907407', 10.0],
       ['1,318.93547453704', 10.0],
       ['924.63349537037', 10.0],
       ['1,090.46725694444', 10.0],
       ['1,824.77277777778', 9.0],
       ['264.6828125', 10.0],
       ['1,085.57243055556', 10.0],
       ['294.985648148148', 10.0],
       ['207.946666666667', 10.0],
       ['1,329.54579861111', 9.0],
       ['2,415.86074074074', 10.0],
       ['1.77890046296296', 5.0],
       ['707.330439814815', 7.0],
       ['34.7596875', 10.0],
       ['1,160.9687037037', 8.0],
       ['830.718055555556', 10.0],
       ['1,300.63256944444', 10.0],
       ['1,890.73599537037', 10.0],
       ['1,095.17435185185', 10.0],
       ['1,687.87', 9.0],
       ['1,330.79913194444', 10.0],
       ['470.644351851852', 10.0],
       ['266.028946759259', 8.0],
       ['1,168.50128472222', 10.0],
       ['1,743.75571759259', 8.0],
       ['186.8365625', 10.0],
       ['1,242.72171296296', 9.0],
       ['1,789.55826388889', 8.0],
       ['8.85586805555556', 7.0],
       ['1,191.73621527778', 7.0],
       ['271.503206018519', 8.0],
       ['1,129.79726851852', 10.0],
       ['614.577060185185', 8.0],
       ['811.313275462963', 7.0],
       ['767.714131944444', 8.0],
       ['2,224.60195601852', 10.0],
       ['680.856967592593', 7.0],
       ['2,212.33505787037', 10.0],
       ['196.905787037037', 7.0],
       ['676.6615625', 8.0],
       ['749.4225', 7.0],
       ['393.519513888889', 9.0],
       ['706.772256944444', 10.0],
       ['1,332.19144675926', 10.0],
       ['1,488.00686342593', 6.0],
       ['202.954513888889', 8.0],
       ['1,345.35858796296', 8.0],
       ['1,793.88021990741', 9.0],
       ['1,740.81190972222', 9.0],
       ['1,137.79262731481', 8.0],
       ['253.339444444444', 8.0],
       ['548.519814814815', 9.0],
       ['1,489.65943287037', 10.0],
       ['1,242.273125', 10.0],
       ['464.199282407407', 8.0],
       ['1,524.42405092593', 8.0],
       ['252.755891203704', 10.0],
       ['964.540532407407', 10.0],
       ['2,085.0755787037', 10.0],
       ['970.78537037037', 10.0],
       ['711.558668981481', 9.0],
       ['606.328784722222', 9.0],
       ['810.802523148148', nan],
       ['1,489.70673611111', 10.0],
       ['1,080.14018518519', 10.0],
       ['647.629571759259', 10.0],
       ['828.888506944444', 8.0],
       ['1,812.52686342593', 7.0],
       ['384.516689814815', 8.0],
       ['611.009131944444', 10.0],
       ['263.71587962963', 9.0],
       ['245.634768518519', 10.0],
       ['46.4427314814815', 5.0],
       ['477.846087962963', 10.0],
       ['558.631365740741', 10.0],
       ['748.742303240741', 10.0],
       ['1,891.95387731481', 9.0],
       ['1,059.65126157407', 10.0],
       ['571.9815625', 7.0],
       ['1,129.4422337963', 7.0],
       ['2.19364583333333', 7.0],
       ['1,497.54341435185', 8.0],
       ['1,032.98957175926', 8.0],
       ['555.410532407407', 8.0],
       ['1,555.58078703704', 9.0],
       ['587.53275462963', 6.0],
       ['596.704502314815', 8.0],
       ['1,849.50445601852', 10.0],
       ['463.423923611111', 9.0],
       ['570.626469907407', 10.0],
       ['1,251.48135416667', 8.0],
       ['501.509027777778', 10.0],
       ['1,695.55283564815', 10.0],
       ['544.607638888889', 8.0],
       ['234.000706018519', 10.0],
       ['377.481053240741', 10.0],
       ['2,397.39950231481', 10.0],
       ['1,034.62446759259', 10.0],
       ['953.540393518518', 10.0],
       ['18.9904861111111', 10.0],
       ['17.4051851851852', 8.0],
       ['179.702372685185', 7.0],
       ['375.68337962963', 8.0],
       ['1,286.45121527778', 7.0],
       ['663.755092592593', 9.0],
       ['603.627962962963', 10.0],
       ['337.319837962963', 10.0],
       ['1,289.53725694444', 10.0],
       ['540.607314814815', 10.0],
       ['315.364351851852', 8.0],
       ['1,227.63363425926', 8.0],
       ['2,041.0740162037', 8.0],
       ['28.3961111111111', 10.0],
       ['833.572465277778', 7.0],
       ['1,087.15978009259', 10.0],
       ['1,028.22833333333', 10.0],
       ['349.032106481481', 7.0],
       ['1,206.90883101852', 5.0],
       ['396.496064814815', 10.0],
       ['347.226967592593', 7.0],
       ['958.898680555556', 10.0],
       ['722.4178125', 9.0],
       ['1,198.53471064815', 10.0],
       ['155.12275462963', 10.0],
       ['1,435.73203703704', 10.0],
       ['2,001.26548611111', 10.0],
       ['1,012.60894675926', 10.0],
       ['1,208.75917824074', 10.0],
       ['746.680381944444', 7.0],
       ['950.113622685185', 10.0],
       ['435.354699074074', 10.0],
       ['1,371.51980324074', 10.0],
       ['1,347.10493055556', 10.0],
       ['697.099548611111', 10.0],
       ['99.0384375', 9.0],
       ['1,425.35289351852', 7.0],
       ['542.473668981482', 8.0],
       ['656.11369212963', 7.0],
       ['137.188229166667', 8.0],
       ['1,442.99334490741', 8.0],
       ['939.470115740741', 10.0],
       ['821.037106481481', 10.0],
       ['354.34818287037', 10.0],
       ['554.863159722222', 10.0],
       ['747.523564814815', 10.0],
       ['763.178657407407', 9.0],
       ['1,478.55788194444', 7.0],
       ['863.464444444444', 9.0],
       ['449.484363425926', 9.0],
       ['6.51122685185185', 10.0],
       ['21.1160416666667', 9.0],
       ['17.9496643518519', 8.0],
       ['822.332233796296', 10.0],
       ['617.114166666667', 9.0],
       ['13.7934143518519', 10.0],
       ['12.4290277777778', 7.0],
       ['34.857650462963', 10.0],
       ['2,392.59760416667', 8.0],
       ['853.064479166667', 10.0],
       ['1,656.5308912037', 10.0],
       ['1,001.64337962963', 8.0],
       ['518.665231481481', 7.0],
       ['1,176.66710648148', 10.0],
       ['99.5446064814815', 9.0],
       ['256.49744212963', 10.0],
       ['1,367.52059027778', 10.0],
       ['1,336.74490740741', 10.0],
       ['1,055.25090277778', 10.0],
       ['510.527766203704', 10.0],
       ['1,001.79449074074', 8.0],
       ['1,032.49072916667', 10.0],
       ['17.9605092592593', 5.0],
       ['1,555.3855787037', 10.0],
       ['1,446.1696875', 10.0],
       ['1,856.33145833333', 9.0],
       ['748.547581018518', 10.0],
       ['915.945081018519', 9.0],
       ['741.581469907407', 10.0],
       ['582.045347222222', 7.0],
       ['977.918101851852', 8.0],
       ['506.448449074074', 10.0],
       ['879.500891203704', 10.0],
       ['804.530844907407', 10.0],
       ['1,212.00530092593', 10.0],
       ['1,574.49334490741', 7.0],
       ['1,010.66149305556', 5.0],
       ['1,251.64925925926', 10.0],
       ['841.638159722222', 7.0],
       ['1,983.53101851852', 8.0],
       ['299.778333333333', 9.0],
       ['2,009.59831018519', 10.0],
       ['985.537488425926', 3.0],
       ['809.664849537037', 10.0],
       ['645.354756944444', 8.0],
       ['642.549803240741', 10.0],
       ['395.689965277778', 10.0],
       ['958.890960648148', 10.0],
       ['2,008.32747685185', 10.0],
       ['1,222.40658564815', 10.0],
       ['1,456.90826388889', 10.0],
       ['1,257.74399305556', 10.0],
       ['769.395868055556', 9.0],
       ['1,149.26971064815', 10.0],
       ['347.353587962963', 10.0],
       ['349.375983796296', 9.0],
       ['773.43587962963', 10.0],
       ['1,397.83141203704', 9.0],
       ['245.458703703704', 10.0],
       ['146.593738425926', 10.0],
       ['1,926.26929398148', 6.0],
       ['1,489.79662037037', 7.0],
       ['143.534618055556', 9.0],
       ['768.448784722222', 9.0],
       ['638.641828703704', 6.0],
       ['1,072.49965277778', 2.0],
       ['958.74630787037', 10.0],
       ['46.5425694444444', 8.0],
       ['649.464710648148', 10.0],
       ['151.867743055556', 10.0],
       ['1,395.2062037037', 9.0],
       ['1,104.97027777778', 10.0],
       ['522.774733796296', 10.0],
       ['61.4710763888889', 8.0],
       ['222.62', 10.0],
       ['1,883.45350694444', 10.0],
       ['1,604.79587962963', 9.0],
       ['1,257.92456018519', 10.0],
       ['608.573287037037', 9.0],
       ['407.831967592593', 10.0],
       ['26.5765277777778', 7.0],
       ['1,276.4119212963', 9.0],
       ['17.5515393518519', 10.0],
       ['1,071.79746527778', 10.0],
       ['1,245.13402777778', 10.0],
       ['20.5593634259259', 9.0],
       ['487.418425925926', 10.0],
       ['1,576.51444444444', 8.0],
       ['613.480335648148', 8.0],
       ['393.449641203704', 9.0],
       ['627.749780092593', 6.0],
       ['1,149.63717592593', 10.0],
       ['1,414.68788194444', 10.0],
       ['1,947.02702546296', 10.0],
```

Comment: I wonder whether you are asking for something that has any meaning.  For instance, suppose older people tended to have larger responses. Including one middle-aged person in a group of younger people would increase the NPS, while including the very same person in a group of older people would decrease the NPS.  In this sense NPS cannot be attributed to age at all, because it is a kind of "emergent" property of an entire group.  Why not just study the relationship *at the subject level* between age and response?

Comment: Thanks @whuber for response. Pleasure and hv learnt a lot from ur answers here.  The age here is the age of using the product. Not the age of the user. You have a very valid point. The idea we are trying to explore is that does age of usage of product has some impact on overall NPS. Now my confusion is that age has a relationship with the response one gives. That response along with all the other response gives NPS. So how to find the effect of age to an overall NPS is am trying to figure out. Like is there some visualization or model I can do to get some sense?

Comment: What do u mean at a subject level? Like u r saying just do regression on age and responses? Or do a correlation? That can be done. Is there some way we can use that info to deduce some impact on NPS? Need to talk about this to executive leadership and we need some way of checking if we can relate impact of individual attributes (like age etc) on overall NPS of the survey or not.